# Vectorized computation of log(n!)

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have an (arbitrarily shaped) array `X` of integers, and I would like to compute the logarithm of the factorial of each entry (Precisely, not through the Gamma function).
The numbers are big enough that

```
np.log(scipy.special.factorial(X))
```

is unfeasible. So I want to do something like `np.sum(np.log(np.arange(2,X+1)), axis=-1)`

But the arange() function gives a different size to each entry, so this doesn't work. I though  about padding with ones, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Can this be done in a vectorized way?

Comment: What's the min and max of X?

Comment: @Divakar Order of ~2500 +- 200

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see what problem you have with the gamma function. The gamma function isn't an approximation, and while approximations may be involved in the computation of `scipy.special.gammaln`, there's no reason to expect those approximations to be *worse* than the error involved in computing the result manually. `scipy.special.gammaln` seems like the perfect tool for the job:

```
X_log_factorials = scipy.special.gammaln(X+1)
```

If you want to do this manually anyway, you could take the logarithms of all positive integers up to the maximum of your array, compute a cumulative sum, and then select the log-factorials you're interested in:

```
logarithms = numpy.log(numpy.arange(1, X.max()+1))
log_factorials = numpy.cumsum(logarithms)
X_log_factorials = log_factorials[X-1]
```

(If you want to handle `0!`, you will need to make a minor adjustment, such as by setting `X_log_factorials[X==0] = 0`.)

Comment: Thanks. And then again for correcting me about the Gamma function

Comment: Nice. Out of interest I tried using approximations by Stirling, Nemes and Ramanujan (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). But while the latter two are pretty accurate at the arguments OP is interested in (2500 +/- 200), all three are actually slower than `gammaln` ;-)

Comment: @Paul Panzer Are you sure? A quick %timeit tells me that the "manual" implementation above is faster for integers as compared to scipy.gammaln for very large numbers.